# Having trouble getting subplots to show up correctly with larger data sets

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having trouble getting subplots to show up correctly with larger data sets.
I am ok with having the figure grow for my application.  I am also ok with having the figure grow such that all the graphs would be about the size of the ones showing up in the small data set example if that is possible.  (anaconda3/v4.2.0/python)

```
    plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout']=True
    figa, axa = plt.subplots(rowcnt, colcnt)
    figa.suptitle("Users Disk Space Usage Over Time.\n")
    ax_index = 0
 
    for r in range(rowcnt)
        for c in range(colcnt):
            n = r * c
            user = gr.columns[n]
            ur = gr[user]
            x = ur.index
            y = ur.values
            while is_color_like(colorpairs[colorindex]) == False or is_color_like(colorpairs[colorindex+1]) == False :
                colorindex = int((colorindex + 2) % (len(colorpairs)/2))
            axa[r,c].plot(x, y, color=colorpairs[colorindex+1], alpha=0.6)
            plt.setp(axa[r,c].get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
            if len(x) > 1:
                axa[r,c].fill_between(x, y, color=colorpairs[colorindex],alpha=0.4)
            axa[r,c].set_ylim(0,disksizebytes)
            axa[r,c].set_title(user)
            axa[r,c].set_xlabel('date')
            axa[r,c].set_ylabel('space used')
            axa[r,c].grid(True)
            i += 1
            colorindex = int((colorindex + 2) % (len(colorpairs)/2))
 
 
 
    detailarryimage = "{}/detailarryimage.png".format(datafolder)
    figa.savefig(detailarryimage)
```

[Small Set Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRYhs.jpg)

[Large Set Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxn2D.png)

Comment: You can change the figure size to suit: `figa, axa = plt.subplots(rowcnt, colcnt, figsize=(5,7))`

Comment: Here's what it looks like with figsize=(5,7)

Comment: Here's what it looks like with figsize=(5,7)  .... can't paste a picture.  Looks pretty much the same except blown up larger. The graphs are still all squished the same. Overall picture size is larger, no extra room used in the graphs...font larger etc...

Comment: 5, 7 was just an example

Comment: Sorry couldn't add the picture.  Basically it looks the same except the entire figure including get squished graphs are enlarged to the new size.  The graphs didn't expand into the new size of the figure.

Comment: I will try different numbers but I don't think the results will change. Seems like I tried this before.   I think the default is 6.4, 4.8 so it did expand the height which should have helped the graphs expand in height but they did not.